Non-stationarity and panel data
Spurious regression happens when we regress two independent non-stationary time-series:
$$y_t = y_{t-1} + u_t \qquad x_t = x_{t-1} + v_t \qquad \operatorname{corr}(y_t, x_t) = 0$$
Then if we do the following regression
$$y_t = \beta_1 x_t + \varepsilon_t$$
We would expect the coefficient $\beta_1$ to be statistically significant with higher than 5 % probability.
But, if we are doing panel data, we usually operate with similar problem:
$$y_{it} = \beta_1 x_{it} + \varepsilon_{it}$$
So, what happens when both $y_{it}$ and $x_{it}$ are unrelated but also RW for all units in the dataset?

The question
How crucial is the assumption of non-stationarity when using (mostly short) panel data? Is it the same as with time series or can we expect the added units to mitigate the problem (even if both variables are non-stationary for all units)?
Do classic methods of panel data (Pooled, FD, FE, RE) solve the problem of non-stationarity in panel data (for, instance, FD performs differences, so it should mitigate the problem of non-stationarity to some degree) and how?
